# Do a select on different column than where clause in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas, ssas-tabular

I wanted to do achieve this “sql” code in a DAX variable

```
Select WeekYearWeekNumber from DimDate where Date = today()+7
```

How can achieve it?

So far I have this code, but it doesn’t work because nextw is more than a column…

```
var nextw = 
FILTER(
            SUMMARIZE('Date','Date'[Week Year Week Number],'Date'[Date]) ,                       
                        'Date'[Date]=TODAY()+7
                         )


var NextWCS = 
FILTER(
            SUMMARIZE(Staff,   Staff[K_Emp],   Staff[StaffingType],  'Date'[Week Year Week Number],   Staff[IsTmed],
                         "sumat", SUM(Staff[Hours])
                         ),                       
                        'Date'[Week Year Week Number]=nextw
                         )
```

Comment: do you want to create a new table or only select one value (like first, min, max) where Date is now +7? And could you provide at least some demo data, even it's just a table in SO, so that it's a bit easier to understand where we com from and what's the goal.

Comment: Select WeekYearWeekNumber from DimDate where Date = today()+7  returns always the same value, so it doesnt matter if it is either select distinct WeekYearWeekNumber      or select max(WeekYearWeekNumber) or select min (WeekYearWeekNumber )

Comment: have you tried something like `calculate(min('Date'[Week Year Week Number]), filter('Date',  'Date'[Date] = today() +7))`

Comment: This OP does not accept any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return a single value for nextw:

```
var nextw = LOOKUPVALUE('Date'[WeekYearWeekNumber],'Date'[Date],TODAY()+7)
```